# Maven sources src/main/java are not seen, advices from same topic not working

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

After creating the Maven Project in Eclipse from maven-archetype-webapp archetype i have the src/main/java not seen in project explorer and advices from same topic here do not work, **so it is not a duplicate, because:**
in my effective POM already stays :

```
  <sourceDirectory>X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\TomkatFromArchetype\src\main\java</sourceDirectory>
    <scriptSourceDirectory>X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\TomkatFromArchetype\src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\TomkatFromArchetype\src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
    <outputDirectory>X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\TomkatFromArchetype\target\classes</outputDirectory>
    <testOutputDirectory>X:\Programming\workspaceEclipse\TomkatFromArchetype\target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
```

what is actualy ok.
But after updating maven, installing, building - whatever, i can not get the damn src/main/java shown in the project explorer and can create new java classes only in src/main/ressources.
I want generally know what is the reason for that behaviour,  options for folders in m2E, so i could turn it and configure in different ways manually.

**Some more info:**

The folder src/main/java is **sort of "exist"**, because if i try to create the folder, it shows that there is one with this name, but is **not seen**.

Opening project properties (right click) -> java build path ,stays 
src/main/java and src/test/java (missing), how can it be?

Solved by looking in the file explorer, is the path realy there.
If it is there,it may be added in project explorer menu. If not - you create it in file explorer and add in project explorer menu

Answer (score 0):

this issue occur into eclipse many time. you need to go to Project property > project facets and click on `convert to faceted from..` then apply and ok. after this you can see the `src/java/main` into your project resources. you can fine image below:

[image]

Comment: no, the facets are already there if you start new web project.
**the solution i finaly found** is go to file explorer and create src/main/java if it is missing and add it the folder via build path->add source folder (in project explorer)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that could work in this scenario(suddenly src main java folder vanishes) is :

1. delete the project from the workspace. (not from disk)
2. re-import the project again as Maven project.

This worked in my case.